# JSON data is not loading in Angular JS when we lauch an app with IIS web server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, apache, iis

I got some severe issue, please help me out.

JSON Data is not loading in Angular JS when we launch an app with IIS web server. When I access it locally without IIS, it works fine without any issues and the same app works fine when I launch it with Apache Web Server.

When I launch it with IIS Web Server, I can see only an empty page; there is no content at all, and there are no errors in the console.

Thanks
Santosh

Comment: Add some code, also check whether the path is correct

Comment: And check your console for errors. If if none, check your network tab for errors. Also try and hit the paths directly and see if they're exposed

Comment: Path and all is correct, it is not displaying the content, only when i launch  the website with IIS Web server..

Comment: It's probably a content type issue, IIS may be passing the request back as text/html instead of text/json. Do the logs say that it is serving the file ok?

Comment: ya, in logs there is no error at all, and it is not executing the JSON file only..  it will executel some javascript files and Stop, and after that there is no error or Warning also... I have added content type, in IIS web server, but also , i am not able to c my Web page..